# Android app with custom URL scheme launching from within Chrome?

Tags: android

I created a basic Android app from the Eclipse wizard. I then added the following intent filter to [AndroidManifest.xml](http://pastebin.com/9Va1EbD9), after the existing one. This makes it support a custom "sample://" URL scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sample" />
</intent-filter>
```

If I run Chrome or the default browser, and click a "sample://" link, it launches my app. However, if I look at the task switcher, my app isn't listed. Instead, Chrome is shown, with my app's screen shot.

Why is this? Can it be fixed? I'm running Android 4.2.2 on a Galaxy Nexus phone.

I notice that if I add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the activity, it opens in a separate app. But the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) say this is "not recommended for general use". Why not?

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you Activity appears in Recent Apps as Chrome is because it now belongs to the Chrome task, because it was launched from there.

As you noticed `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` solves your problem, however it is not recommended or discouraged because it would brake the user experience and navigation and how users expect your application to behave.

Fortunately, I think there's a way of specifying Intent flags in your `HREF`, try something like this:

```
<A HREF="intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=com.example.package/.MyActivity;end" />
```

in the previous example `launchFlags=FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This flag is generally used by activities that want to present a "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of separate things that can be done, which otherwise run completely independently of the activity launching them.

Comment: Really? Wouldn't you expect that if you launched an app from a URL, you could switch back and forth between that app and your browser, just as if you had manually launched the app? Maybe I'm more used to the iPhone UX, but this seems strange.